# Inheriting a base class

Tags: inheritance, active-directory, forms-authentication

I am trying to use forms authentication with Active Directory but I need roles (memberOf) from AD. I am trying to override members of RoleProvider to make this possible (unless someone knows of a better way). I am stuck on an error in the new class that is inheriting from RoleProvider.

The error is:
ADAuth.ActiveDirectoryRoleProvider' does not implement inherited abstract member 'System.Web.Security.RoleProvider.ApplicationName.get'

How do I set up all the other members that I am not overriding? Do I have to create them all in my inherited class or is there a way to tell it to just use the ones from the base class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to override any abstract elements of your base class.  If they are marked abstract, it means the base class does not provide a default implementation, so you cannot call it.